# QGIS manually select overlapping features/data points

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I am trying to manually  select features visualized on a map to change an attribute of several features at once by highlighting them on the map using the "select features tool".

I'm using the multi edit toggle so that I can modify field data for all selected features at attribute table. The problem is that there are so many data points/features that are in the same location or close proximity that I cannot verify each point is selected, and it appears that features that are not visible are not being selected/the attribute change is not applied.

How can I select (and deselect) manually all features in the geographic area that I am selecting? Essentially, I am trying to clip manually.

Comment: Are they all in the same layer?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has many methods of selecting all the features in a specific geographic region. Note that all of *these methods only select features in the currently active layer*.

**The "select features" tool has the following modes:**

- Select features
- Select features by polygon
- Select features by freehand
- Select features by radius

[image]

Any of the last three modes will select all the features in a geographic area (for the currently active layer). With each of these modes, you draw a shape on the map (polygon, circle or freehand shape), and all the features within that shape are selected.

**There's another select features tool with more advanced options**, next to the first "select features" button.

[image]

With "select features by expression" you can write an expression that selects all the features that meet a certain criterion. The criterion can be anything you can define in an expression. For example, this expression selects all features that intersect the polygon with vertices at (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0) and (0, 0).

```
intersects($geometry,geom_from_wkt('polygon(0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)'))
```

**In the attribute table, you can choose to only show features visible on the map**. Then you can select all the rows shown in the attribute table. Now you have selected all features visible on the map. (Including any features hidden by overlapping symbols.)

[image]